# How to fix cart form content

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

WordPress 5.1.1
WooCommerce 3.6.1
woocommerce-cart-form-contents layout issue

Removing product image and thumbnails globally caused cart form layout issue (woocommerce-cart-form_contents). Using one page checkout & cart. Also, using full cart on landing page where issue most obvious.

Left column for thumbnail on cart page persists.

www.flamebroilercatering.com

I've tried the following:

`````
````margin-left: 0 !important;
````}

Removed <td class="product-thumbnail"> from cart.php but left most column persists. 

Removed <th class="product-thumbnail"> from cart.php but left most column persists.

Modified table from 6 columns to 5 but left column for thumbnail persists and rest of columns squashed. 

5. Added align="left" to table with no effect


````.cart .woocommerce-cart-form {
````margin-left: 0 !important;
````}

After removing thumbnail with remove_action expected cart form content to shift left.
`````

Comment: I found CSS that worked to remove column 1 but also removed the product summary. Wondering if thumbnail and product summary tied together? I can use following CSS to remove columns in cart form but again, the first column takes out product summary. ````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````                                             .woocommerce table.cart td:nth-of-type(1), .woocommerce table.cart th:nth-of-type(1) {
display: none; ! important
}

Comment: Using this CSS able to expand size of column 1 but float left still no result. .woocommerce table.cart td:nth-of-type(1), .woocommerce table.cart th:nth-of-type(1) {
float: left; width: 300px; !important;
}